# Is order preserved in the transaction sequence API of pg-promise?

Tags: query-optimization, pg-promise

I have to insert a lot of records, and some columns have foreign keys from other tables. The way to do it in pure SQL is something like

```sql
INSERT (foo, fk) VALUES (1, (SELECT id FROM f_table WHERE blah = 'something'))
```

But on massive insert this is too slow (~5000 ms for 5000 rows in my use case). I'm already using the `tx.sequence` function to speed up the insertion of the dependency records, but to speed up the insertion of the dependent records, could I return the id's from the first query (in batches) and would the order be preserved?

for example,

```
const h = pgp.helpers

// insert dependency records
const registersCs = ColumnSet(['name', 'address'], { table: 'register' })
const metrics = await t.sequence(index => {
        const batch = results.slice(index * batchSize, (index * batchSize) + batchSize)
        if (batch && batch.length) {
          try {
            const bulk = `${h.insert(batch, registersCs)} ON CONFLICT (name, address) DO UPDATE ${h.sets(/* yada yada */)} RETURNING id`
            return t.many(bulk)
          } catch (err) {
            log.error(`Error inserting registers: ${err.message}`)
          }
        }
      }, {dest: (index, data) => { results[index].registerId = data.id }})

// insert dependent records, which now has the registerId I was originally going to have to use a subquery for...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could I return the id's from the first query (in batches)

You can replace `t.many(bulk)` with `t.map(bulk, undefined, a => a.id)`. And [sequence](https://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#sequence) supports option `track` to accumulate all resolved data.

> and would the order be preserved?

I don't see why not.